# Linq ThenBy() throwing "The best overloaded method match ThenBy() for has some invalid arguments" exception

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following method:

```
public List<LambdaExpression> defaultSortExpressions { get; set; }

private IQueryable<TEntity> orderEntries(IQueryable<TEntity> entries)
{
    var n = 0;
    foreach (var sortExpression in defaultSortExpressions)
    {
        if (n == 0)
        {
            entries = Queryable.OrderBy(entries, (dynamic)sortExpression);
        }
        else
        {
            entries = Queryable.ThenBy(entries, (dynamic)sortExpression);
        }
        n = n + 1;
    }
    return entries;
}
```

When the `TheyBy()` line is executed, I get the following exception:

> "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Linq.Queryable.ThenBy(System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' has some invalid arguments"}
>   System.Exception {Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`entries` is strongly-cast at compile-time as an `IQueryable<TEntity>`, whereas `ThenBy` needs an `IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>`. You could try casting `entries` as `IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>` before passing it into `ThenBy()`. Or you could capture the result of the call to `OrderBy` in a separate variable with the correct type to call `ThenBy` on.

```
private IQueryable<TEntity> orderEntries(IQueryable<TEntity> entries)
{
    if(defaultSortExpressions.Count == 0)
        return entries;        
    IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> ordered = Queryable.OrderBy(entries, (dynamic) defaultSortExpressions[0]);
    
    foreach (var sortExpression in defaultSortExpressions.Skip(1))
    {
        ordered = Queryable.ThenBy(ordered, (dynamic)sortExpression);            
    }
    return ordered;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `== 0` rather than `< 0`. `List<T>.Count` will never return a negative number, but the code will currently break if the list is empty.

Comment: Thanks!  Both the example code given and casting `entries` as `dynamic` work.

Comment: @im1dermike: Jon also pointed out in the answer that he deleted that you can cast it as `IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>` rather than dynamic. I prefer to reduce usages of `dynamic` as much as possible.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks for catching that. Fixed.